# Can I get the source text of JavaScript functions in C++ callback function using google v8?

Tags: javascript, c++, v8, embedded-v8

I am embeding google v8 into my C++ program. I want to get the source code of Javascript functions passed as arguments into my C++ function. For example:

```
function ComputePixel(nir, red, blue) {
    return (nir-red)/(blue-red)
}
var layer = L8.function(ComputePixel, {
    ‘nir': L8.select('B5'),
    ‘red': L8.select('B4'),
    ‘blue': L8.select('B2’) })
```

Here "L8.function" is my C++ callback function. Is there any way I get can the complete source of ComputePixel in my C++ function?

Comment: `ComputePixel.toString()`?

Comment: L8.function is a callback function in C++ registered in V8. I would like to get the source of the first argument of it. So it means I have to use C++ code to do this.

Comment: Then you should post what you have on the C++ side of things.  `v8::String::Utf8Value str(args[0]->ToString());`  doesn't work?

Comment: yes, it works. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call ToString on it:

```cpp
v8::String::Utf8Value str(args[0]->ToString());
```